# « Violate » et « violer » en physique

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, synonymes, physique

Je suis physicien et enseigne à l'université. Je ne suis pas un locuteur natif du français. En anglais on peut employer une phrase comme celle-ci :

> This statement violates the first law of thermodynamics.

Comment peut-on traduire cela en français ? Moi, je pensais en employant le verbe violer. Mes collègues francophones natifs (non ingénieurs et physiciens) disent que dans ce contexte, les deux verbes sont des faux-amis.
Violer s'emploie plutôt signifiant un rapport sexuel avec quelqu'un sans son consentement. Cependant, mon dictionnaire dit que l'on peut l'employer signifiant enfreindre (c-à-d ne pas respecter un règlement, une loi). Comment faut-il donc traduire :

> "This statement violates the first law of thermodynamics."

ainsi que

> "This is a violation of the first law of thermodynamics"

etc. ?

Comment: Je suis un étudiant ingénieur français. Le dictionnaire est correct. Dans ce contexte, cet utilisation est normale.

Comment: Peut-être une autre question ou qqn. a qqc. à ajouter sur _contrevenir_ voire _contredire_ en contexte ? Merci !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Violer" et "enfreindre" peuvent l'un et l'autre être utilisés pour désigner une expérience qui contredit une loi physique. Il me semble qu'il y a une légère préférence pour "enfreindre". Ainsi, on dit: "cela enfreint la seconde loi de la thermodynamique".

Cependant, dans le cas des inégalités de Bell, "violer" est plus souvent utilisé.
"Cela viole les inégalités de Bell". "Les inégalités de Bell sont systématiquement violées"

On notera que sans contexte, le mot "violer" évoque bien plus "commettre un viol", qu'il n'évoque l'idée d'enfreindre quelquechose.

Le mot "violation", lui, offre moins de double sens. L'équivalent français pour "a rape" n'est **pas** "une violation" mais "un viol". "Une violation" peut être utilisé légalement, avec l'idée d'une effraction ou d'une infraction, ou bien plus rarement en science, par rapport aux lois de la physique.

---

Edit: Dans [sa réponse](/a/33887/3911), @dimitris propose "transgresser", ce qui constitue aussi une bonne alternative à "violer".

Comment: Avec tous les bémols habituel quant à l'usage des Ngram, l'usage d'enfreindre semble en croissance depuis 1970 et a dépassé violer dans ce contexte depuis le début des années 90:

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=violer+la+loi%2C+enfreindre+la+loi&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cvioler%20la%20loi%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bvioler%20la%20loi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvioler%20la%20Loi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cenfreindre%20la%20loi%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Benfreindre%20la%20loi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Benfreindre%20la%20Loi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BEnfreindre%20la%20loi%3B%2Cc0

Comment: C'est sans compter les occurences d'enfreindre **à** la loi, qui s'entend, mais ne se retrouve pas dans le corpus

Answer (score 14):

Je confirme ce que dit loxaxs, le terme "violer" ne s'emploie pas seulement pour un rapport sexuel non consenti, on peut aussi l'utiliser dans le sens de "violer une loi", "violer une règle, un règlement", etc.

Je traduirais donc "This statement violates the first law of thermodynamics" par :

- "Cette affirmation enfreint la première loi de la thermodynamique" (plus adapté ici je pense)

ou

- "Cette affirmation viole la première loi de la thermodynamique"

Answer (score 6):

Effectivement, « violer » peut signifier « enfreindre ».
On peut tout à fait employer « violer » dans ce contexte :

> Cet énoncé viole la première loi de la thermodynamique.

De même dans un cadre plus général, on peut enfreindre la loi ou la violer.

Answer (score 1):

En complément aux excellentes réponses. On rencontre la tournure "*violer une loi*" dans la bible (Jean 1 3.4) :

> Bible du Semeur : Celui qui commet le péché viole la Loi de Dieu, car le péché,
> par définition, c’est la violation de cette Loi.
>
> Bible Segond 21 : Tous ceux qui pratiquent le péché violent la loi, puisque le péché, c’est la violation de la loi.

En revanche, la version 1910 de Segond emploie *transgresser* :

> Quiconque pèche transgresse la loi, et le péché est la transgression de la loi.

---

Voici un exemple d'usage contemporain en physique

http://sensphysique.com/energie/machines-mouvement-perpetuel/

Voici un exemple d'usage contemporain en mathématiques. L'extrait est tiré de l'ouvrage *Scientific Computing with MATLAB and Octave* (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-45367-0) :

Since F is a proper subset of R, elementary algebraic operations on floating-point numbers do not enjoy all the properties of analogous operations on R. Precisely, commutativity still holds for addition (that is fl(x + y) = fl(y + x)) as well as for multiplication (fl(xy) = fl(yx)), but other properties such as associativity and distributivity are **violated**.

La [traduction en français](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Calcul_Scientifique/zctJAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Comme%20F%20est%20un%20sous-ensemble%20propre%20de%20R,%20les%20op%C3%A9rations%20alg%C3%A9briques%20%C3%A9l%C3%A9mentaires%20sur%20F%20ne%20jouissent%20pas%20des%20m%C3%AAmes%20propri%C3%A9t%C3%A9s%20que%20sur%20R.%20La%20commutativit%C3%A9%20est%20satisfaite%20par%20l%E2%80%99addition&pg=PA6&printsec=frontcover) rend l'extrait comme suit :

Comme F est un sous-ensemble propre de R, les opérations algébriques élémentaires sur F ne jouissent pas des mêmes propriétés que sur R. La commutativité est satisfaite par l’addition (c’est-à-dire fl(x + y) = fl(y+x)) ainsi que par la multiplication (fl(xy) = fl(yx)), mais d’autres propriétés telles que l’associativité et la distributivité sont **violées**.

Comment: La plupart des pays francophones sont principalement de tradition catholique, où peu de gens lisent la Bible. Son impact sur la langue est négligeable. Et ce en plus du fait que comme en anglais ou toute autre langue, les traductions anciennes utilisent une langue ancienne qui n'est pas forcément représentative du français d'aujourd'hui, et parfois même pas du français de leur époque.